# sas - get max value of variable in multiple rows/columns

Tags: max, sas

I have the following data...

```
ID     SEQ     BEGINDATE     ENDDATE
111     2      20MAY2013     21JAN2014
111     2      20JAN2014     .
```

I want to get the maximum date from either the `BEGINDATE` OR `ENDDATE` field for each `ID` & `SEQ` combination. So for the above, I'd like to end up with the following result...

```
ID     SEQ     FINALDATE
111     2      21JAN2014
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
data want;
set have;
by id seq;
retain finaldate;
if first.seq then finaldate=.;
finaldate = max(of finaldate begindate enddate);
if last.seq then output;
keep id seq finaldate;
run;
```

Use RETAIN to operate across rows.  `max` can take any number of arguments, so across columns isn't an issue.